# Convert a double index sequence into a single index sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Suppose I have a double index sequence $\{x_{n,m}\}$ in $\mathbb{R}$. Am looking for a bijection $f:\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ such that $\{x_{n,m}\}$ converges if and only if $\{x_{f(n,m)}\}$ converges.

In other words, I would like to transform a double index sequence into a single index sequence without affecting convergence. This is in order to use results about single index sequences for my double index sequence.

Is this possible? The usual diagonal enumeration of $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ won't work here because $k>f(n,m)$ does not imply $n_k>n$ and $m_k>m$, where $(n_k,m_k)=f^{-1}(k)$.

Note: By convergence of a double sequence I mean $x_{m,n} \to x$ if and only if for all $\epsilon>0$ there exist $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $m,n\geq N$ implies $\mid x_{m,n}-x \mid < \epsilon$.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: What do you call *the usual diagonal enumeration*?

Comment: And what limit are you referring to when you say $(x_{n,m})$ converges? ($\lim_{m\to\infty}\lim_{m\to\infty}$, or maybe $\lim_{(n,m)\to(\infty,\infty)}$? If the latter then any bijection $f$ works...)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I mean $x_{m,n} \to x$ if and only if for all $\epsilon>0$ there exist $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $m,n\geq N$ implies $\mid x_{m,n}-x \mid < \epsilon$.

Comment: The "Cantor diagonal argument" is completely unrelated to enumerating $\Bbb N^2$. While there are several variants, I assume you mean something like this: $$N(n) := \max\left\{N\in \Bbb N : \dfrac {N(N+1)}2 \le n\right\}\\M(n) := n - \dfrac {N(N+1)}2\\ n \mapsto (N(n) - M(n), M(n))$$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Can you show this svp? It doesn't seem obvious to me.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Yes sorry this is what I mean.

Comment: Forget what I said about every bijection working. In  fact the question makes no sense  as stated, and when I try to concoct a meaingful version of the question what I get has the property that _no_ bijection works. See Answer below....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we need to note that the notation in the question makes no sense: If $f:\Bbb N^2\to\Bbb N$ is a bijection and $(x_{n,m})$ is a double sequence then " $\{x_{n,m}\}$ converges if and only if $\{x_{f(n,m)}\}$ converges" is impossible. Because there's simply no such thing as $x_{f(m,n)}$, since $f(m,n)\notin\Bbb N^2$.

There are various ways to state the natural question that seems likely to be what the OP really meant to ask about, for example

> > **Q.** Does there exist a bijection $f:\Bbb N \to\Bbb N^2$ such that for any doubly-indexed sequence $x_{m,n}$ we have $x_{m,n}\to x$ (as defined above) if and only if $x_{f(k)}\to x$?

The answer is no, there is no such bijection. Given $f$, choose $k_n\in\Bbb N$ with $$f(k_n)=(0,n).$$

> > **Easy Exercise.** $\lim_{n\to\infty}k_n=\infty$.

Now let $$x_{m,n}=\begin{cases} 1,&(m=0),\\0,&(m>0).\end{cases}$$ Then $x_{m,n}\to0$. But $x_{f(k_n)}=1\not\to0,$ and since $k_n\to\infty$ this shows that $$x_{f(k)}\not\to0.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. You are right my question is not well-formulated. The way you framed it is what I intended to mean.

Comment: Regarding the exercise, if $\lim k_n \neq \infty$, then there would exist a natural number $N$ and a subsequence $k_{n^{'}}$ of $k_n$ such that $k_{n^{'}}\leq N$ for all $n^{'}$. Since $f$ is a bijection this would imply that there are infinitely many natural numbers less than or equal to $N$, a contradiction. Is this correct?

Comment: @Alphie The idea there is exactly right. You really can't use the notation $k_{n'}$ for a subsequence of $(k_n)$.

Comment: You don't like this notation? What about $k_{n_{l}}$?

Comment: @Alphie Yes, the correct notation for a subsequence of $(k_n)$ is $(k_{n_j})$.